# jQuery: Slide panel delay on load

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a side panel that is expanded on page load, slides closed on click and uses a cookie to stay closed on refresh, what I have works great.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8ccv03s/14/)

```
$('#slideClick').click(function () {
var it = $(this).data('it') || 2;
switch (it) {

    case 2:
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '-345px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(".slideClose").addClass('hideBtn');
        $(".slideOpen").removeClass('hideBtn');
        break;

    case 1:
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '+=345px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(".slideOpen").addClass('hideBtn');
        $(".slideClose").removeClass('hideBtn');
        break;

}
it++;
if (it > 2) it = 1;
$(this).data('it', it);
//$.cookie('myCookieName', '1')
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 1;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("myCookieName", "foo", { expires: date });
});
```

If possible id like the panel to be closed on load and expand/slide out after 2 seconds, I have tried modifying "case 1:" and ended up breaking it repetitively as this is outside of my jQuery knowledge, any help would be appreciated.

**update** I tried using ".delay(2000)" before .animate with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: you want it expended 2 seconds after page loads ?

Comment: Yeah at the moment it loads already expanded, I want it to expand 2 seconds after the page is loaded if that's even possible without rewriting the whole script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use a `setTimeout` to delay function execution 
https://jsfiddle.net/u8ccv03s/20/

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#slideClick').click()},2000);
```

This is from your code ;) I provided you a fiddle

To prevent the glitches I added css to be default hidden :) So you can check example above, and I left your cookies as you wanted but you'll want to clear them to see the effect.

Comment: Cool that seams to do the trick, I do get a split second flash/jump when the page loads of the panel, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry it also breaks the whole cookie setup and now doesn't remain closed on page change/refresh

Comment: ah, you wanted it with cookie setup,  no problem

Comment: Perfect, what ever you do, you need a raise :)

Comment: If my answer helped , than it's correct to mark it as correct :p